# View not updating after app suspension/resumption

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a component in which i subscribe to an Observable. In the callback i set member variables in that component. Those variables’ values will then be displayed on the component page.

But, when the app goes out of scope (e.g. by manually doing so or by the Android OS-Popup asking for location permission) and comes back in, the view is not updated anymore (though the callback still receives new values as the console log proves).

A working example would a blank starter app with the following content of the homepage class (requires the cordova geolocation plugin)

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  lat = 0;
  long = 0;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation,
              private zone: NgZone)
  {
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log('constructor() Subscribing');
    this.renewSubscription();
  }

  renewSubscription()
  {
    if(this.subscription)
    {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      this.subscription = null;
    }

    this.subscription = this.geolocation
                            .watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy : true})
                            .subscribe(this.onLocationChange);
  }

  private onLocationChange = (location: Geoposition) =>
  {
    if(location.coords)
    {
      console.log(location.coords.latitude + ':' + location.coords.longitude);

        this.lat  = location.coords.latitude;
        this.long = location.coords.longitude;

    }
    else
    {
      console.dir('no coordinates');
      console.dir(location);
    }
  }

}
```

and the following as a replacement for the Home page html  content

`{{ lat }}:{{ long }}`.

As a bit of searching, i suspect that after the app resumption many of the the code does not live in the angular zone anymore or something like this, because when setting `lat` and `long` inside the zone explicitly it works again

```
this.zone.run(() => {

        this.lat  = location.coords.latitude;
        this.long = location.coords.longitude;
      });
```

The thing is that this is a very over-simplified version of the app i'm working on - which has a lot of subscriptions and indirections, so i was not able to find the code i have to put inside the angular zone manually.

Is there a way to run the app's code within the angular zone after app resumption just like it would after a normal app start?

**EDIT**

Putting the code into `platform.resume` won't work either.

Comment: ngOnInit() might be the problem, it is only fired once when entering a page. Try placing `this.renewSubscription();` in ionViewWillEnter(). ionViewWillEnter is always fired when entering a page.

Comment: @TomasVancoillie this would assume, that after an app resumption the subscriptions would be deleted. Which is not the case. Also, i did try to put the code into a platform.resume-subscription, which did not solve the problem either.